# spring-cloud-netflix - Where is the code that actually reflects or checks the presence of the annotation @EnableZuulProxy?

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to understand Netflix zuul support provided by spring-cloud-netfix (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix). There are multiple annotations like @EnableZuulProxy and @EnableZuulServer but did not find the code that checks the presence of this annotation and take action.

What exactly is happening behind the scene in presence of the above mentioned annotation and where is the code for it? It is important to understand the magic that is happening behind the scenes.